# URL Rewrite 2.0 installation fails on Docker

Tags: dockerfile, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to get URL Rewrite 2.0 installed using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY obj/Docker/publish .
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/E/C9E8180D-4E51-40A6-A9BF-776990D8BCA9/rewrite_amd64.msi /install/rewrite_amd64.msi
RUN net start MSIServer
RUN msiexec.exe /i c:\install\rewrite_amd64.msi /quiet /passive /qn /L*v "C:\package.log"
```

When I build the container image, I see this error message:

**The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.  This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed.  Contact your support personnel for assistance.**

Looking at package.log after running the container, I see this:

```
SI (c) (30:A4) [08:32:10:438]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80040150
SI (c) (30:A4) [08:32:10:438]: Note: 1: 2774 2: 0x80040150: 2774 2: 0x80040150
```

Executing `net start msiserver` on the running container returns a message that the service is already started, and Google says 0x80040150 could be a problem reading the registry.

Is it expected that installing URL Rewrite this way should work, or do I need to elevate permissions somehow?

**Update**: Running the same `msiexec` command on the *running* container successfully installs URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to [this article](https://blog.sixeyed.com/how-to-dockerize-windows-applications/).  Using PowerShell to run `msiexec` with the appropriate switches works.  Oddly, it threw "Unable to connect to the remote server" when trying to also *download* the MSI using PowerShell, so I resorted to using `ADD`.

Here's the relevant portion of my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /install
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/E/C9E8180D-4E51-40A6-A9BF-776990D8BCA9/rewrite_amd64.msi rewrite_amd64.msi
RUN Write-Host 'Installing URL Rewrite' ; \
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'rewrite_amd64.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: The URL for the .msi has changed. For URL Rewrite version 2.1 x64 (English), it is now https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi. You can find all the versions at the bottom of this page: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: The URL for the .msi has changed. For URL Rewrite version 2.1 x64 (English), it is now https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi. You can find all the versions at the bottom of this page: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite